# How do I go about adding a place in google maps for china?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I know how to add a place in google maps en, but now my client asked me that he also would want to add a place for google maps china, this is the code that I use for adding a place in en:

```
        string apiUrl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/add/json?key=MY_KEY";
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(apiUrl);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            Google google = new Google
            {
                location = new Coord { lat = branch._Latitude, lng = branch._Longitude },
                name = branch.BranchName,
                phone_number = branch.ContactNO,
                address = branch.Address,
                types = new string[] { "clothing_store" },
                language = "en"
            };

            var myContent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(google);
            var buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(myContent);
            var byteContent = new ByteArrayContent(buffer);

            byteContent.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(apiUrl, byteContent);

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var data = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                GoogleResult googleResult = new GoogleResult(data);
                return googleResult;
            }
        }
```

I also tried changing the url for the chinese version but it didn't work, I debugged mode and saw that the IsSuccessStatusCode yields to false... For what its worth here is my poor attempt at going about it:

```
        string apiUrl = "http://maps.google.cn/maps/api/place/add/json?key=MY_KEY";

    // ...

            Google google = new Google
            {
                location = new Coord { lat = branch._Latitude_Chi, lng = branch._Longitude_Chi },
                name = branch.BranchName_Chi,
                phone_number = branch.ContactNO_Chi,
                address = branch.Address_Chi,
                types = new string[] { "clothing_store" },
                language = "zh-CN"
            };
```

I've also looked everywhere and to no avail I've come here, thanks in advance guys!

Comment: is weird that you are using different domains in your `apiUrl`. `maps.googleapis.com` vs `maps.google.cn`

Comment: According to google, google map for china is hosted differently so maybe I thought saving the place to that domain is logically correct but I guess not...

Comment: If that comment helped you, im going to post it as answer, so you can mark it as helpful

Answer (score 0):

Try using the same domain in both calls to the API. Actually you are using `maps.googleapis.com` and `maps.google.cn`

Comment: Using the first domain which is working would work but it would save it in English form and not in Chinese form which is what I'm trying to achieve.